# ios - how do I make an app which I developed on the iPhone storyboard also work on the iPad?

Tags: ios, ios5, storyboard

I have an app that is nearing completion. So far I have just been using the iPhone storyboard to map out the navigation, but I would also like the app to work on the iPad. Is there a way to just "make it work" or do I have to re-do by hand the entire app flow on the iPad's storyboard?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering they have different resolutions, and aspect ratios, you really just have to grin and bear it, and convert it all manually.  You can at least copy the storyboard file to a new one, and adjust the views one by one to be ipad-sized

Comment: you know, for Android, they do allow a phone app to be used on the tablet devices. I tried it...it looks all stretched, but at least it is available. Would that also be the case for the iPad? That it would work but look bad? Or actually creating the iPad storyboard is the ONLY way?

Comment: You can set your project to use your iphone storyboard file for both iphone and ipad, but it won't look good

Comment: @GeekedOut You can create an iPhone-only app, and it will still be downloadable on the iPad with that built in "x2" button.  That's similar to what you mention about Android. (This issue is also one of the many reasons I choose not to use Interface Builder, but that's a personal preference ;)).

Answer (score 1):

If you made it a universal app, I'd suggest creating another storyboard targeted for iPad and work from scratch. You can still use all the controllers and methods therein for your new views (considering there's nothing very specific) with some slight modifications to adjust for the iPad.